# Strange characters in textbox after receiving via socket

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

I've written small tcp socket client and server applications. Server sends text msg to client.

Part of servers code:

```
new_sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("efgh"));
```

Part of clients code:

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

 int count = sock.Receive(buffer);
 sock.Close();
 textBox_received.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

In windows forms application everything is OK but in WPF application after received text always appears "boxes":
[image]

What is the reason and what can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the string from the whole buffer of 100 bytes, while you actually only received a few. You should only do [Encoding.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3.aspx) on the bytes you actually received:

```
textBox_received.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer,0,count);
```